# How can I change access permissions across many pages?

Tags: user-access

Is there a way to change who can access a large subset of pages at once?

Comment: please be more specific.... front end, back end? what kind of access?

Comment: Front-end, or read privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Not right now. In the next version of WordPress there will be custom bulk actions, then it'll become easier to do.

Maybe for now you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-bulk-actions/. Unfortunately that'll require some coding on your part.